# Why does the substrate of a MOSFET need to be lightly doped?

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors, fet, silicon

[image: MOSFET structure]

Image source: [Electronics Tutorials - The MOSFET](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_6.html)

MOSFETs were briefly discussed in my advanced materials class last semester and after reviewing the material, I was confused why does the substrate need to be lightly doped? From what we learned, a positive voltage on the gate will attract electrons of the heavily n-doped drain and source, forming a channel, and repel the holes of the lightly p-doped substrate. However, I don't understand why the substrate needs to be lightly doped. Would it work if it was just pure undoped silicon instead?

Comment: asker - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be a source webpage link & added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) To remind yourself of the main site rules, please see the [tour] & [help]. Thanks.